# Chaining hash by dividing

Tags: python, хеширование

Есть задача,что существует 2 массива, в одном значения, во втором суммы. Как проверить есть ли таких 2 значения в 1 массиве сумма которых равна числу со второй с помощью chaining hash?

Answer (score 0):

Проверить, есть-ли два числа в первом массиве такие, что их сумма равна числу из второго массива - можно. Полным перебором.

```
zn=[7,1,10,3,4,3,8,5,6,8,2,9]
sm=[17,5,9,12,9,18]
for i in sm:
    for j in zn:
        for k in zn:
            if i==j+k:
                print (i,"=",j,"+",k)
```

Это общий случай.

Если данные упорядочены, и/или в данных нет повторений  - то количество операций можно сократить, введя соответствующие проверки.

А вот с какого боку тут chaining hash - и хеширование вообще - совершенно неясно. Проясните.

Comment: Всё что есть в условии - это таблица должна состоять из массива,числа которых будем сравнивать с суммой. Вот  мне нужна Ваша помощь, чтобы понять как это применить вообще

Comment: Условия задачи лучше узнавать/уточнять у того, кто эту задачу вам задал, а не заставлять других гадать, что да почему. Мы даже не знаем в каком курсе/разделе/теме вам ее задали.  Так какая помощь может быть?